# Post 1 Scenario failure Scenarios marked as Failed (ThreadLocal<WebDriver> tldriver = new ThreadLocal<>();

Tags: cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Hello can anyone please advise for below case.
I have implemented Cuc7+Junit5 to run scenarios in parallel, I have 34 scenarios to Run in parallel
'cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=2' in Junit properties
Now what happens is if due to some reason if a Scenario fails (case is not handled by script or session hangs) then that browser instance will remain orphan the 2nd browser is executing post its completion then 2 browsers are opened again which is Fine.
But at end Cucumber Report marks all scenarios failed post that 1 Scenario failure that browser instance that got orphan, Unclear as how we handle this case...
When all Pass report is displayed as expected.
I am using Cucumber html report + Json and Json is used for Azure
Below is driverfactory class , TextContext, PageObjectManager

```
public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> tldriver = new ThreadLocal<>();
    
    public static WebDriver getdriver()
    {
        System.out.println("property file read");
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("Browser");
        logger.info("Browser read is: " + browserName);
          
        if (tldriver.get() == null) {
            tldriver.set(createDriver(browserName));
            DriverFactoryMy.
            logger.info("New WebDriver instance created for thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
        
       return tldriver.get();
    }
```

```
public static void quitdriver() {
        WebDriver driverInstance = tldriver.get();
        if (driverInstance != null) {
            try {
                driverInstance.quit();
                logger.info("WebDriver instance successfully closed for thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getId());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Exception occurred while quitting the driver: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                tldriver.remove();
                logger.info("WebDriver instance removed from ThreadLocal variable for thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("WebDriver instance is null for thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    }
```

```
private static WebDriver createDriver(String browser) {
        logger.info("Browser value is: {}", browser);
        WebDriver driver = null;
        if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        } else if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else {
            logger.error("Please pass the correct browser value: {}", browser);
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

```
Junit properties file:- cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=2

Text Context() used for DI
    public TestContext() throws InterruptedException {
        pageObjectManager = new PageObjectManager(DriverFactoryMy.tldriver);
        scenarioContext = new ScenarioContext();
        }

PageObject Manager
public PageObjectManager(ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver) {
    System.out.println("Thread ID in PageObjectManager is == " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        this.driver = driver;
    }
public LoginPage getLoginPage() {
return (loginPage == null) ? loginPage = new LoginPage(driver) : loginPage;
}
```

As every driver instance is new then how can be have report being not impacted?

Comment: Sir @M.P. Korstanje can u please advise.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think I understand the question. Could you have a look at these pages to help you clear up your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and maybe also create a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sir @M.P.Korstanje apologies for being unclear. ..I will explain. When execution starts we have 2 browser thread opened and if 1 thread execution fails ( browser remains idle) 2nd browser continues execution and then again we have 2 browser thread opened so now (1 idle +2 New thread) all scenarios executed post idle will be marked as failed there are no steps to reproduce, so report is issue.

Comment: That's too vague unfortunately. You'll have to narrow this down much more. Remember you are asking complete strangers for help with a professional problem. If you don't do the work, noone can help you.